# .Net Core WebApi How to use AD for authorization

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I've seen a million different answers and none of them work.

Can someone please give me a link that works for:

I have a web api, I've registered it on Azure.  I have Azure Active Directory configured.

I have a tenantId, a clientId, a client Secret, and every other variable I should need.

I can log a user into my system through AD via an MVC controller, how can I do the same with web api?

I basically need to generate the AD token so I can continue to use the API outside of my MVC controllers.

It must be the same token, because I need to access microsoft graph from the client side of the API.

HELP!

Comment: Seriously how is this so messed up...

Comment: All I want to do is:

1.  Create a .NetCore WebApi and authenticate it using Azure Active Directory

Comment: then, let me request the azure active directory token with postman, and then use that token.  but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It’s up to the client to get a token and pass it to your API. You don’t specify what the client is (I.e. web, iOS, Android) but since you’re using Azure AD you could just use the appropriate ADAL library provided by Microsoft to do this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries

Comment: These are the same links i've been looking at.  None of them work.

Answer (score 0):

> I can log a user into my system through AD via an MVC controller, how
>   can I do the same with web api?

If you are interested in server-to-server interactions without direct interaction from the user side, you may have a look at [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow for AZAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

The attached article contains simple examples of implementation.  I think for your case, [example with a daemon/console app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2) (just replace it w/ Web API) is what you need. Download the example, replace configurations (Instance, TenantId, ClientId, and ClientSecret) in appsettings.json w/ yours, and try to play around with it.

Comment: These are the same links i've been looking at.  None of them work.

Comment: @TomCrosman Please specify which error/problem do you have when you run an example with a daemon. It should be straightforward.